# My bootstrap navbar side menu does not appear above inner content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, textbox

Is there a .css style that will allow my menu to always appear on top of the inner content?

[image]

**The textbox use class="form-control".**

[image]

**My menu css:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.navbar-default{
position: relative;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: It was z-index: 3; that fixed it.  Thank you marif.